# How to set page number in Page View Control in Objective-c

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

How to set page number in top of the page view control for every pages using Navigation item in Objective-c?

```
self.navigationItem.title=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(%lu to %lu)",(unsigned long)_dataArray.count,(unsigned long)_indexpath.row+1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it work for me.

```
  - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController 


  *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController


 *)viewController

  {
  NSUInteger index = ((PageViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

  indexpaths=index;

  self.navigationItem.title=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:

  @"(%lu to %lu)",(unsigned long)_dataArray.count,

  (unsignedlong)indexpaths+1];

  if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {

    return nil;

  }
  index--;
   return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
  }

 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController 

*)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController 

*)viewController

 {

   NSUInteger index = ((PageViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

   indexpaths=index;

  self.navigationItem.title=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(%lu to 

   %lu)",(unsigned long)_dataArray.count,(unsigned long)indexpaths+1];


   if (index == NSNotFound) 
     {

     return nil;

   }

   //self.navigationItem.title=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(%lu

  to %lu)",(unsigned long)_dataArray.count,(unsigned long)indexpaths+1];

  if (index == [self.dataArray count])
   {

    return nil;

  }

 index++;

  return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// config
UILabel *headlinelabel = [UILabel new];
headlinelabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:28];
headlinelabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

// set title string
headlinelabel.text = @"YourTitle";

[headlinelabel sizeToFit];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:headlinelabel];
```

Comment: first thanks for your response. i think you i did not understand my question clearly. i need to show the page number at each page while appear of each pages